# How can I add a line feed into a Xamarin.Forms label?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is what I would like to do:

```
<Label Text="Choose By\nOne\nTwo" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

However the only thing this does is make the characters \n appear twice in the label.  Is there any way that I can add a line feed in as part of a label's text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this, but for me I was sending a string from a server to the device and needed a way to keep line feeds in the text. I ended up having to process the text on the device and find my special `<THIS IS A LINE FEED>` character and replace it with `Environment.NewLine`.

So something like this:

In your XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Something}" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

OR

```
<Label x:Name="LabelMy" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

Then in code behind or ViewModel:

```
string normalText = "Choose By\nOne\nTwo";

string fixedText = normalText.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);

ViewModel.Something = fixedText;

//OR

LabelMy.Text = fixedText;
```

Comment: @Alan2 How about you let me know what didn't work before down voting each answer?

Comment: It's not me that down voted you.  I will check out the answers when I am back in work.  Thanks for taking the time to come up with an answer.

Answer (score 11):

You should use

```
<Label Text="Choose By &#10;One &#10;Two" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

and the result will look like `\n`

[image]

Comment: Still works as intended for Xamarin Forms 5 (pre-release)

Comment: this is not working if your data comes from the view model

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `\n` by `&#x0a;`. Or set it in a more verbose mode like:

```
<Label Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Label.Text>
        Choose By
        One
        Two
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will check this out.